# How to create a table-like row with a <ul> that has elements of non-uniform height

Tags: html, css

I have a given markup that I'm trying to apply to some style on. Having little (but some) flexibility with the markup, and would ideally like to do this in CSS only, if possible.

Each of the `<li>`'s divs are of variable height based on content, but in the end, I would like to end up with all `<li>`s of equal height (height of largest column).

What is the best way of doing this?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >
<head>
<title>Table row</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: yellow;
}

li
{
    display: inline-block;
}

li div
{
    width:200px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="divA" style="background-color:red;">
        hello<br/>world
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="divB"  style="background-color:blue;"/>
        hello<br/>world hello<br/>world
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="divC" style="background-color:green;"/>
        hello<br/>world hello<br/>world hello<br/>world
        </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This can not be done with CSS alone if the content of the divs are variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want every `<li>` to have the height of the tallest `<li>`, these are your options:

- Hardcode the height of the `<li>`s, or
- Use JavaScript to programmatically compute and apply the height, or
- Use a table.

Answer (score 1):

here is a good way of solving this problem.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KYWyE/1/)

what was done is just floating the `<li>` tags to left; and right after the parent ul closes i added an empty div with a clear:both css property.

Note for the float to be effective and not collapse to the next line i added a width to the parent element, which can be a div, but in your case the body element.

Comment: That clearly does not set each `<li>` to the same height (at least in Chrome): http://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxo3D.png

Comment: that will not set height. but the next element element will come only after the biggest li. you have a nice effect

Comment: I do not think that is what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for...

```
function equalHeight(li) {
    var tallest = 0;
    li.each(function() {
        var thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if(thisHeight > tallest) {
            tallest = thisHeight;
        }
    });
    li.height(tallest);
}

equalHeight($("li"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/p2we3/

Code from here: http://www.cssnewbie.com/equal-height-columns-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to wrap the ul in a div.  Set the height of the div.  Set the ul/li's to height:100%.  - not sure if this will work.  If you use spans/divs instead of li's it will.

Alternatively, you can use javascript after loading to find all the heights then go back through and set the heights to the max found height.

Answer (score 0):

The working solution with set clear:both; property

```
 var ch=$("#container").width();

    var itemsPerRow=Math.floor(ch/102);

    var itemsCount=$("#contentpane li").length;
    var loopRound=Math.floor(itemsCount/itemsPerRow);

    for(var i=1;i<loopRound+1;i++)
    {
        var nextFirstItem=i*itemsPerRow+1;

        $("#contentpane li:nth-child("+ nextFirstItem  +")").css({"clear":"both"});
    }
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CmkSb/9/)